# How to remove javascript code as gmail does?

Tags: javascript, asp.net

I am currently working on securing my javascript code. I am using Asp.net 4.0 When i was checking my mail on gmail I just right clicked & selected view source & It just showed me `<html><body></body></html>` . Can i implement this type of security in my application or any other best security feature that will hide/encrypt my javascript code

Comment: Not sure what you're talking about....when I view source I've got all of their code...

Comment: I'm totally lost. What? Gmail doesn't remove javascript code.

Comment: click "view page source" and you'll start seeing some javascript :)

Comment: I think you clicked on the top frame in the gmail window which apparently has no HTML by default (the content must be added by javascript).  If you do a view source on the message list, you see all sorts of Google code.  So, your supposition about Google hiding their HTML/JS is wrong.

Answer (score 2):

No, short of obfuscating it, there's nothing you can do to prevent somebody from seeing your code. Even then, obfuscating it only makes it more difficult to interpret, not impossible.  Javascript is interpreted by the client's browser.  The only way for it to be executed is for the source code to be available to the browser at runtime.  In order to "encrypt" it, you would need to then provide the encryption key to the browser which would defeat the purpose of the encryption all together.